# How do I load weighted split tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I do the weighted split by this code:

```
half, quarter, quarter2 = tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit(weighted = [2, 1, 1])
```

After that I try to load the split data by:

```
dataset = tfds.load('mnist', split=half)
```

But I get the error:

```
AssertionError: Unrecognized instruction format: NamedSplit('train')(tfds.percent[0:50])
```

What is the right syntax for loading.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution to your problem was using this type of slicing

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

s1,s2,s3 = "train[:50]","train[:25]","train[:25]"
dataset= tfds.load('mnist', split=s1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The api tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit has been depreciated. It doesn't work with tfds 2.1. Eshan solution is correct.